# This scrapy code enters data into the wrong form (search form). How do i get to the actual login form

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I was trying to log into a website using scrapy and it always inserts the data in the first form i.e the search bar.
I have tried to do every possible thing that i could understand

```
  start_urls = [

        'https://www.exportleftovers.com/account/login'
    ]

def parse(self, response):
    token = response.css('form#customer_login input::attr(value)').extract_first()
    print(token)
    return FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={

        'form_type': token,
        'customer[email]': 'anything',
        'customer[password]': 'anything'

    }, callback=self.start_scraping)
```

It should log into the login form but it puts the value in the search bar

Answer (score 1):

Use `formid`:

```
def parse(self, response):
    token = response.css('form#customer_login input::attr(value)').extract_first()
    print(token)
    return FormRequest.from_response(
        response=response,
        formid="customer_login",
        formdata={
           'form_type': token,
           'customer[email]': 'anything',
           'customer[password]': 'anything'
        },
        callback=self.start_scraping
    )
```